A movie where a person is electrocuted on the street?
I think this was the end of the movie where it was either in the middle of winter or a bad rain story where a guy who maybe maybe glasses and bushy hair wearing a rain cost that either yellow or red or whatever color and he stops his car out in the middle of the street where there is a metal railing and he goes up toward the railing and i think he was on ice or water whe suddenly those electric phone lines split either due to ice or lighting and he is immediately electrocuted when he is either touching the water or railway. It was either this or he slipped and hit his head where he slid down the road while either dead or unconscious. It looked like a 90s-early 2000s or 80s movie. I think the guy, when he got hit, slid downhill and hit the railing.

Looks like a final destination movie to me.

Hi Cameron. A couple of things: 1. Please try to add punctuation. Most of your question is one run-on sentence that's hard to follow. 1. Please try to add any background information you can possibly remember: Year, country, general plot, genre, possible actors, other scenes etc.

The Ice Storm from 1997 has a character resting on a guardrail and the getting electrocuted.  There is a storm as well. 
